# Rest Service Time of a M/M/1-FIFO queue

Tags: markov-process, queueing-theory

How to derive the value for **rest service time** from arrival rate λ and mean service rate μ in a M/M/1-FIFO queue?

Is this correct?  `System time = Waiting time + η(service time) + (1-η)(rest service time)`

edited: I am not clear on what rest service time is. Actually it is another thing that I wanted to know. Does below make sense?

Since,

```
System Time = Waiting Time + Service Time
```

and maybe,

```
Service Time = Time Served by Server + Other(Rest) Service Time
```

Comment: What do you mean by "rest service time"?

Comment: @Math1000 check the edited question please

Comment: It's still not clear what you're asking.

Comment: I didn't get what you want to express with "rest service time" too. Do you mean the time that the server was idle? But if it processed the item in the system and already served it, the service time is already done and the server is only waiting to receive more items.

Comment: I added a screenshot of the question which I was looking the answer for. Please check part c to whether you can get an idea.

Answer (score 0):

correct equation is, 
[Mean waiting time] = [service rate].[Mean number in queue] + [rest service time of a job in service]

`[service rate].[Mean number in queue]` <- actual time need to complete for all items in the waiting queue.

`[Mean number in queue]` <- [arrival rate λ].[Mean waiting time]; by Little’s law;

Comment: can you explain what is meant by "rest service time"?